# Cannot start MongoDB: System error 1067 in Windows

Tags: mongodb, database

After setting up MongoDB service on Windows Server 2008 R2 this error was raised.

```
C:\mongodb\bin>net start MongoDB
The Mongo DB service is starting.
The Mongo DB service could not be started.

A system error has occurred.

System error 1067 has occurred.

The process terminated unexpectedly.
```

Comment: did you add mongodb in your environment variable ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The error came from an unclean shutdown detected.

Please visit http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/repair for recovery instructions.

a few steps will fix it (as it's written in the link above):

1) remove the file `/data/db/mongod.lock`

2) run `mongod.exe --repair`

3) start the mongod service `net start MongoDB`

Comment: For others having this problem, when I followed the installation instructions to this point I had left open a copy of the command prompt with mongod.exe running, creating a lock on the data. Closing this command prompt allowed me to start the service successfully.

Comment: Thanks - helped me! As what to do if this does not help: in step 3 do not start it as a service but start it in the console. This way you get directly the log output and any error that happened during startup. For me for whatever reason the windows pagefile was disabled and some feature depends on it to be there and large enough.

Comment: If you read the log file you may find additional information about the issue. In my case, I was trying to spin up a mongodb server v3.6 on a data folder with mongodb files v3.0.7. So, first I have to update those files to v3.4 [before mongodb server v.3.6](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#upgrade-procedures) can update them .

Comment: Make sure you run it with any --config as well

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who faced this error on 2020, with version 4.4.1 of mongo, and the accepted answer not solve the issue, here is what I've done:

1. Remove all mongo services from pc (add/remove programs).
2. Go to program files and backup the MongoDB folder.
3. Remove the MongoDB folder.
4. Re-install mongo db.

And it should work.

**UPDATE** for January 2021, the following saved me without re-installing MongoDB and losing all my data:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin>mongod --dbpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\data" --repair
```

Comment: Still works for December 2021.

Comment: --repair Still works!

Comment: --repair using '--dbpath' still works!

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue and I closed the other command prompt which was opened with mongoDB.exe, and hence created a lock on that executable. Simply only closing that command prompt window worked fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Same with me, had another cmd window open after I ran `To start MongoDB, run mongod.exe. For example, from the Command Prompt:` on Step #2 -- https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have at least 5 Gb available space on the drive of the database. For me, clearing that space enabled the ability to restart Mongodb.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the Windows. you should change the mongodb's config in the System disk.For example

1) I change `C:\Windows\system32\mongodb.exe`.

2) And I make the path  in `D:\mongodb\mongod.cfg` .Before this,you should remove previous.

3) Finally , you can net the serve. `net start mongodb`.

I hope it can help you .English is not very good ,please forgive me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCRwq.png)

Comment: Step 2 was my issue, an old installation on mongodb was blocking the new one from starting. Tnx

Answer (score 2):

I was having the problem of starting the the MongoDB. The logs are pretty descriptive and you can find suggestion from there.

There is a '**d**' folder that needs to be created within **data** folder like 
**data\d** which was missing.

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Although, not an ideal solution, I ended up deleting all of the database files in `\data\db` and was then able to successfully run the `MongoDB` service. Note, this will delete all of the data in the database.