# MongoDB system error 1067 while stopping a windows service

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mean.io

I have installed mongoDB using [Mongo Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) in c drive not in program files and created data/db and log folder in c drive.

I have also created the config file inside the mongoDB folder and windows server also created. I am now successfully staring the windowsservice using below command

```
net start mongoDB
```

But when i tried to stop the mongoDB service using `net stop mongoDB` it is showing some system error and then stopping the service. The error is shown in below fig

[image]

I am afraid t as this causes any breach or corrupt the Data in the MongoDB. Can anyone guide me to solve this problem

Comment: Perhaps this answer is useful for your http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670273/cannot-start-mongodb-system-error-1067-in-windows

Comment: @BenjaminGuttmann I had tried that steps but didn't work.